# Stack div elements in css vertically (with dynamic height)

Tags: css, html

I'm trying for hours now to get the following working:

I'd like to have three divs in an container div.

1. They need to be stacked vertically (topDiv, middleDiv, bottomDiv)
2. the topDiv should be 20px tall (fixed)
3. the middleDiv should take the rest of space left (like * in a table or \vfill in LaTeX)
4. the bottomDiv should be 50px tall (fixed)

that does not sound so hard does it? I just can't figure it out!

thanks for your help.

Comment: is the container a fixed height, or does it stretch with the contents of the middle div?

Comment: This should get you going in the right direction: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

Comment: @Evert the container is always as high as the browser window. At: Henrik Ammer i didn't even come near to what i am looking for. What i have now is topDiv and bottomdiv positioned absolute but i don't now what to do to get the middleDiv between them that's where i'm stuck.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do perfectly. You can set fixed position on the top and bottom ones, then do a middle div with a margin/padding that is as large the heights of the other divs. But you can't stretch it perfectly to the browser window. You need to set a % height to scale it with the browser window, but you can't combine that with the fixed margins.

Comment: @Rasmus, I disagree: It is possible to do it perfectly using absolute positioning without percentages. See the second jsfiddle sample in my answer. This may fall over with very old browsers, but  I have successfully tested it on most modern browsers (ie6+).

Comment: Oh, Did not know you could set height by specifying top + bottom. Good to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like this may work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/nCrEc/1/

edit:

this version scales with the browser window
http://jsfiddle.net/nCrEc/2/

html:

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.con{width:200px; top:0;bottom:0;left:0; position:absolute;background:#ff0;}

.top{width:200px;height:20px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:#f60;}

.bottom{width:200px;height:50px;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;background:#f60;}
.middle{width:200px;min-height:1px; position:absolute;bottom:50px;top:20px;left:0;background:#06f;}
```

Comment: This doesn't scale with browser height.

Comment: @Rasmus that was not specified in the original question, but thanks for the downvote anyway :)

Comment: +1 for negation. @Evert is right, it doesn't specify scalable to browser window in the question. He also provided a workable solution similar to what I would suggest.

Comment: +1 for @Evert fixing the solution to be scalable. [http://jsfiddle.net/nCrEc/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/nCrEc/3/) is an update, `.con` doesn't need `position` at all. works IE7+, Chrome, FF

Comment: Sure the question was not extremt clear, but point 3 hints at it very strongly

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm. Is it the `min-height` attribute which causes the div to take the rest of the height?

Comment: Glad to help. It's the combination of a top and bottom absolute position - the div will always try to stay 20px from the top and 50px from the bottom. The min-height is so IE7 renders correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with [Flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/#flex-direction-property) but it is still being developed and only really works in Chrome at the moment.

Otherwise, you can use [`* {box-sizing: border-box;}`](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) to make your life easier. There is even an [IE6-7 polyfill](http://html5please.com/#box-sizing) if supporting old browsers is important to you.

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LAlxd).

```
*{-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; padding:0;}
html,body{width:100%; height:100%;}
div{width:100%; background:salmon;}
.middle {background:lightblue; height:100%; padding:100px 0;}
.top, .bottom {height:100px; position: absolute; left:0;}
.top {top:0; }
.bottom {bottom: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar on this website:

http://www.probusllandudno.org.uk/

click the dinners 2012 link (and, if using FF web developer, u can use  view generated source)

The main points are putting the divs in order in the doc, assigning fixed width (in my case) or width=100%, top and botom divs have fixed height see the css

ADDENDUM

Another response offers a sophisticated solution that covers issues around most specifically padding.. You haven't specified how your content might influence the solution. My web page is just centered text