# Two Stacked divs and controlling heights

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack two divs A and B.

Div A - will be scrollable but its height needs to be determined by the div underneath it, Div B so if the content in Div B changes, and it's height changes the height of Div A also changes.

Div B - needs to be aligned to the bottom of page on top of a absolute positioned footer. Its content needs to be aligned to the bottom.

I've tried using position relative and float by wrapping these divs in a wrapper, but the whole thing breaks when I try to keep the Div B aligned or positioned absolutely above the footer.

I've got a feeling this needs to go back to basics, any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: Can you make JSFIDDLE of whatever you tried ?

Comment: Can you explain your layout?  It looks like you have three major elements on a page: Div A, Div B and Footer.  You say that the Footer is absolutely positioned, but where? the bottom of the viewport? the page? do you mean fixed? Is the entire page suppose to take 100% of the viewport? If so, how much room does Div A need for a minimum height? So if the height of Div B increases, what happens to the height of Div A? You need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeh sure, here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/aa2xK/

Comment: Div A is essentially the Content area, it requires around 75% of the height. But Div B needs to be able to freely auto change its height dependant on its content. The footer is fixed to the bottom of the page. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example. I *think* I have correctly understood your requirement. This example has them appear to be stacked but in the HTML they are not actually stacked, they are nested. I wasn't sure if you could allow that in your solution but fingers crossed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jyR2A/1/

CSS:

```
#divA {overflow-y:scroll;position:absolute;height:100%;top:-100%;background:green;width:100%;}
#divB {position:absolute;bottom:0;background:blue;width:100%;color:white;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divB">

    <!-- Div A is nested so we can use divB's height -->
    <div id="divA">
    </div>

    <!-- Div B content -->
    <div id="divBinnerContent">

        Line 1 <br />
        Line 2 <br />
        ..Keep adding more lines to test how it works <br />

    </div>

</div>
```

How it works:

divB is the parent element defining the height of divA. So if we set divB position relative or absolute and place divA inside then we can set divA's height to 100% to give it the height of parent element divB.

Now to position divA we make sure it has position:absolute and set top:-100% which will move it up the same distance as the height of its container divB. Position absolute not only allows us to position it correctly but it also removes it from affecting the height of its parent, divB.

And the content for divB I have made a nice container for it but it is not neccessary. Simply put it anywhere inside divB (but not inside divA) and it will be OK.

You can use the content to define the height,as I have, or use an absolute height set in CSS.

Hope this is what you were after.

Le-roy

Comment: This kind of seems to work - how could I then change the height of Div A?

Comment: What do you mean? I thought you wanted divA to be the same height as divB, or a percentage of it? If you are manually setting the height of divA doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: Well, not so much it's height be controlled directly by Div B but more that when Div B's height changes Div A's height changes by the same amount. So if one line of text is added to Div B, Div A's height reduces by one line and so on

Comment: Alright, gotchya. So, assuming as before that you only need the 'effect' and that you don't neccessarily need to achieve it with two divs stacked on each other then you can use a table. Just set the height of the table to 100%, or whatever your height, and set two rows. the first row is 'divA' and the second row is 'divB'. Give the second row a height of 0 and the first row no specific height. This will make the table adjust automatically. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Mgp5v/1/

Comment: Very nice! Why do you need a table though? Can I not use a div to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think so. But I wouldn't rule it out for anyone that wants to try! I can't think of a way but if I do, I'll let you know.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. You can emulate a table using div elements. http://jsfiddle.net/Mgp5v/2/

Comment: Overflow will only work on a DIV with regular display so we need an inner element to achieve that http://jsfiddle.net/Mgp5v/3/

Comment: Great, that works really well. I'm gunna look at maybe utilising something like this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this with help from this question and fiddle.

[Stack div elements in css vertically (with dynamic height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532398/stack-div-elements-in-css-vertically-with-dynamic-height)
http://jsfiddle.net/nCrEc/334/

Essentially the answer was giving my Div A a height without using the height parameter but instead using absolute positioning on top and bottom. Which meant changes to Div B changed the location of the Div A's bottom (oo er) which pushed the middle div up whenever another populates the bottom area.

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

then using this CSS

```
.con {
width:200px;
top:50px;
bottom:0;
left:0;
position:absolute;
background:#ff0;
}
.top {
width:200px;
height:20px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#f60;
}
.bottom {
width:200px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:#f60;
}
.middle {
overflow-y:auto;
min-height:1px;
position:absolute;
bottom:50px;
top:20px;
left:0;
background:#06f;
}
```